# Wordpress Site - Author as URL to Archive

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

within a Wordpress based website, I am trying to make changes to posts so viewers can click on post's author and will be redirected to site with authors all posts/ archive. Currently I have tried amending a code:

```
<?php get_author_posts_url( $author_id, $author_nicename ); ?>
```

but it did not help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Post your code!

Comment: Can you give us your code ?

Comment: Create a author.php in your theme, write some code that checks who the autor is, after that you can loop that authors posts and print them.

Comment: edit does not let me insert entire code here, what should I do?